# Python Pandas - Take first value from column and put into a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame (df) that I get from an input (uses SQL to get data):

```
| Grant      | Summary     |
|:-----------|------------:|
| J0014/1    |  foobar     |
```

It will only ever be one row.

How do I get the value from the Summary column into a variable to use later i.e. I dont want the column header, I want a situation where this happens:

aVar = foobar

Apologies if this is a simple question, but for some reason my brain isnt working this morning. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpliest is select first value of column by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
aVar = df['Summary'].iat[0]
```

Solutions with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), 
[`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), because [ix indexer is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated):

`iloc` is for select by positions, so need position of column `Summary` by [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
aVar = df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('Summary')]
```

`loc` select by names, so use:

```
#default index - first value is 0
aVar = df.loc[0, 'Summary']
#general solution with unique index - seelct first value by `[0]`
aVar = df.loc[df.index[0], 'Summary']
```

Comment: Ahh, perfect. Thank you Jezrael! To be honest, I have never seen '.iat' before so it wasnt as stupid question as I originally thought!

Comment: Also, thank you the extra explanation for the other methods. Much appreciate to help me learn!